# How to handle roles with flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have this issue I want to create two roles for my app, medic and patient so with flask login we create a class of user for handling restrictions in our app, but how can I these to roles to my user model for handling information acording to the role.

This is my user model

```
from flaskblog import db
from flaskblog import login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader # decorator para validar si el usuario está autenticado
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username= db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email= db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file= db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password= db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    '''Relacion uno a muchos '''
    # un usuario puede ser autor de uno o muchos posts
    # db.relationship describe la relacion entre el usuario y el post
    # tiene tres params 1: nombre de la clase con la que se establece la relacion}
    # 2: backref con la cual se establece la forma de la relacion el usuario sera el autor del post
    # 3: lazy la forma en que se cargan los datos
    post = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True) 

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User( '{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

I can create the models for medic and patient but how to really handle information acording to these roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add roles to your model like this, I used this with Flask-Security. Add this to your User object:

```
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='roles_users', backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

and add the Roles object

```
class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

finally add the many to many relationship

```
roles_users = db.Table(
    'roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
    )
```

with this setup, you can decorate routes with one of these

```
@roles_accepted('medic', 'patient')
@roles_required('medic')
```